# How to Copy a table from MS Access and Change in .txt or other format?

Tags: c#, database

I am making a program for embedded PC. Till now I have been writhing code in a Normal PC and was using MS Access as Database, use to read directly from Access.

```
    public static DataTable GetAccessDataTable(string TableName, string DatabaseName)
    {
        if (TableName == null) return null;
        if (TableName.Length == 0) return null;
        try
        {   // Iniciate DB connection

            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\" + DatabaseName;

            OleDbConnection DbConnect = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from " + TableName, DbConnect);

            DataTable DT = new DataTable(TableName);
            DataAdapter.Fill(DT);

            return DT;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is that I dont have Access in my Embedded PC and I am in no mood to install it. So I wanted to convert the Access Datatables into .txt or something light. Where I could use DataTables (from Windows.Data). I dont want a database in my Embedded PC atleast for testing. In Future a database will be there but its not decided yet by my project and I want to test my code on the Target hardware. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data in datatable then you can use DataTable.WriteXml to write the files in XML format.[Example here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or you can write it as csv file using stringbuilder streamwriter

```
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
 //write columns
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        result.Append(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
        if(i == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
        result.Append("\n");
        }
        else
        {
        result.Append(",");
        }

    }
     //write rows       
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            result.Append(row[i].ToString());
           if(i == dt.Columns.Count - 1)
           {
            result.Append("\n");
           }
           else
           {
           result.Append(",");
           }
        }
    }

    //write result to a file        
   StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"your file");
   file.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It Looks promising and was exact to the point.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Any consideration of using SQL Lite? Or I would recommend using XML files since its easily portable to DataTables.

[DataTable.WriteXml()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think SQL Lite will be used finally. But for now What shall I use to make a copy of AccessDatabase Tables so I can use it for testing purposes.

Comment: Just create a loop for all tables and then use DataTable.WriteXML() method